# How can I create a javascript extension Method that I don't have to pass the string into

Tags: javascript

For Instance lets say I have a `isNullOrEmpty` function defined like so.

```
String.prototype.IsNullOrEmpty = function (o) {
   return o == null || o == '';
}
```

I want to be able to say something like this:

```
var s = 'test';
s.isNullOrEmpty
```

and get the answer as `false` or `true` for that string.

Comment: `this` in your method will be a reference to a string wrapper object. So do `var o = this + ""`. Not sure the purpose of the `null` test. Seems like you could just do `return !this.length`

Comment: If the variable is `null`, then the `IsNullOrEmpty` method of the String prototype won't apply to the object to which it's chained/applied; therefore the `o == null` can never evaluate to `true`. What is it you're actually trying to check for? And why?

Comment: squint you are correct, can you post your response as an answer so I can mark it. The reason for the null check is because I come from a .Net background. I will have to revise the function names.

Thanks Everyone for the information and assistance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This can't be done with JavaScript.  `null.anything` will always be an error.
I assume you have a .NET background, because Extension methods in .NET do behave this way.  But it will not work with JavaScript.

The only thing you could do would be `"string".isEmpty()`, but you'll need to include the `()`, because JavaScript doesn't have good enough support for "getter properties" that work without the `()`.

To do that, you'd need:

```
String.prototype.isEmpty = function() { return this === ''; };
```

Comment: Actually, JS provides perfectly good support for getter properties that work without the `()`.

Comment: Torazaburo, can you provide an example because if I try to do this without the () it does not work. It will write out the function text and not run the function.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function using the syntax:

```
expression.function()
```

the value of the expression will be in `this`. So you should write it as:

```
String.prototype.IsNullOrEmpty = function() {
    return this == '';
};
```

As mentioned in the comments, it can never be `null`. If it were null it wouldn't be a string, so nothing from `String.prototype` would be called, unless you did something perverse like:

```
Stirng.prototype.IsNullOrEmpty.call(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
!str
```

since empty strings are falsy, as are nulls. (However, note that this approach would also return true for `undefined`, boolean values of false, or numeric values of 0.)

If you really, really, want to call this test as a method on strings, you can make `"abc".isNullOrEmpty` work (as a "property", with having to say `isNullOrEmpty()`), by saying:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'isNullorEmpty', {
    get: function() { return this === ''; }
});
```

However, as mentioned elsewhere, this would never be called in the case of `null`.